# I have a problem with unhandled exception in c with quick sort

Tags: arrays, c, visual-studio, recursion, quicksort

This is a code for the quick sort that I wrote. I had to do the **quick sort** with **pointers**. I have a problem on line 9. The error is with unhandled exception . Also if I have a problem you can tell me where I'm wrong.

```
void swap(int* l, int* r)
{
    int buff = *l;
    *l = *r;
    *r = buff;
}

void* split(int* l, int* r)
{
    int anchor = l[(r - l) / 2];
    while (1)
    {
        while (*l < anchor)
            l++;
        while (*r > anchor)
            r--;
        if (l >= r)
            return;
        swap(l, r);
    }
}

void qsort(int* l, int* r)
{
    if (r > l)
    {
        int* anchor = split(l, r);
        qsort(l, anchor);
        qsort(anchor + 1, l);
    }
}

a[] = { 100, 20, 200,30,300,40,400,50,90 };

void main()
{
    qsort(a, a + sizeof a / sizeof * a - 1);
}
```

Comment: Whatever book you're learning from, please throw it away. It shows you how to use old pre-standard C where one could implicitly define variable of type `int`. It haven't been allowed the last 30 or something years.

Comment: As for the crash, take this as an opportunity to learn how to use a *debugger* to catch crashes and locate when and where they happen in your code, and how to examine variables and their values.

Comment: It probably also helps to say what the error is.

Comment: Dare I ask what value you were going to return from `split` ? It claims a `void*` result, but returns *nothing* (several times). This code is *begging* for a warning -flags jack-up and treating them as errors. Unrelated, you could not have picked a worse name for your quicksort than `qsort`. The moment you need to include `stdlib.h` for *any* reason the code will break with a multi-decl error. `qsort` is already in the standard library.

Comment: As I already wrote I need to write the quick sort myself. The function name was given to me by my teacher.

Comment: Not going to sugarcoat it; that person is a lunatic if they're suggesting you *ever* use the same name as standard library functions. [See here](https://godbolt.org/z/q5fT8c6hY).

Comment: Also I edited the code now it moves some elements but not all. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Please crank up the warning level! The compiler should tell you something along "return without value from non-void function `void *split(int*, int*)`".

Comment: Right now the *only* thing in this code that isn't problematic to one degree or another is the `swap` function.  If you build with warnings raised and treat them as errors (which they *are*), your compiler should bark loudly. Again, [see here for an example](https://godbolt.org/z/q5fT8c6hY)

Comment: Your edit makes this a completely different question. Don't "fix" the code in the question in response to comments or answers (unless it's about plain typos when writing the question itself). If you have another problem then ask another question.